# "create is not valid input at this position " when using mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql

I have just installed mysql-workbench and type my first a few line of code,

the first line "`show databases`" runs well,

but when it comes to "`create database wenda`"

it reports "`create is not valid input at this position`"

why?

Comment: My guess is that you have left first command on first line and typed second command on a second line. In that case you need to put semicolon after the first command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss the ";" after the first line.
try

`show databases;
create databese wenda;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget ";" after create table

> CREATE TABLE xxx ( content ) *;*